# How to configure OData not handle non-odata exceptions in Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I want to use OData in Web Api for few Action methods in a Controller. What is happening is that once i enable OData in Web Api, the error message format is getting changes for all error . 
Is there any way to configure Odata only for specific controller/action routes.

Error Message before Enabling OData looks like:

```
{"Message":"User Name/Password are invalid ."}
```

Error Message after Enabling OData looks like:

```
{
  "odata.error":{
    "message":{
      "lang":"en-US","value":"User Name/Password are invalid ."
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to configure OData to handle only specific controllers so that rest of the APIs have no impact of OData setting. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

One of the big changes we made between RC and RTM is that we've completely removed the EnableOData extension method. We realized that registering OData formatters globally was a bad idea because it impacts controllers regardless of whether they're meant to be OData controllers.

So, in our v1 release for OData and in our current nightly builds, we've added a new base class called ODataController. If you derive from ODataController (or EntitySetController), you will automatically get support for OData just for that controller. It shouldn't affect the rest of your controllers the way it does now. You should also use config.Routes.MapODataRoute instead of EnableOData.

You can install our latest nightly build using these instructions:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/06/01/using-nightly-asp-net-web-stack-nuget-packages-with-vs-2012-rc.aspx

It should be pretty stable at this point.

Comment: hi - I'm a bit new to odata but I think I get it, anyway, if I were to get that latest build, would it out-of-the-box support server side ordering and filtering as in the example for a kendo UI grid here: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/remote-data.html

Comment: Absolutely, all you have to do is add the [Queryable] attribute to your action once you install the OData package

Comment: Are you required to use "config.Routes.MapODataRoute"? I am using the AttributeRouting package where in my routes are defined directly on the action method itself. How does this work with OData routes?

Comment: @YoussefMoussaoui Okay, but I'd love to expose reuglar non-OData HTTP Get method and when I do (in ODataController) I got an **No non-OData HTTP route registered.**.